# Magento 2 - Multiselect broken

Tags: magento2

I'm testing to add a multiselect input in my BO form. But, the multiselect output is broken (however, the value selected is really selected in BO, and values are assigned). When I select a value, the multiselect selects all the values (all the values are highlighted ; just graphically).

My XML :

```
<field name="my_field">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Config\Source\Content\TagSelect</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Tags</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

**TagSelect File** :

```
public function toOptionArray()
{

    return [
        ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST],
        ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => 'test'],
        ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => 'test']
    ];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please code of `TagSelect`

Comment: Please see the second block of code

Comment: where you have implement this muiltselect .At ui form of admin or checkout

Comment: I implement it in ui_component, for form here

Comment: 'value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST should not be same for all option.

Comment: ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST],
        ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => 'test'],
        ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => 'test']
    ];  all three option has same option vallue>it is wrong

Comment: `namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Config\Source\Content;

class TagSelect implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
 $options[] =['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST];
        $options[] = ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG2TEST, 'label' => 'test2'];
        $options[] = ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG3TEST, 'label' => 'test3'];
        return $options;
    }
} `

Comment: Oh ok, that was because all my 'value' has the same value. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

**As per as, Amit Bera comment:**

All the option's value is the same  `MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST` that why you are getting the issue. **Each option value should be unique like**:

```
public function toOptionArray() {
    $options = [];
    $options[] = ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST, 'label' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG1TEST];
    $options[] = ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG2TEST, 'label' => 'test2'];
    $options[] = ['value' => MyInterface::TAG_TAG3TEST, 'label' => 'test3'];
    return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**After toOptionArray Function Call Below Function**

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
       return $this->toOptionArray();
}
```